# Стоит ли использовать AAAA запись в DNS?

Tags: сеть, dns

Везде пишут что AAAA запись это эквивалент A записи, но только для IPv6. Так ли это и стоит ли использовать AAAA вместо A при формировании DNS?

Например, у меня есть сервер. От него есть IPv4 и IPv6. В DNS панели (Route53) я хочу добавить AAAA запись.

Мне эта идея пришла в голову на фоне всевозможных блокировок подсетей. Стоит ли так делать и какие могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: Если вы хотите использовать IPv6 - делайте, не хотите - не делайте

Comment: @andreymal вас понял. Я просто думал что есть какие-то нюансы. Спасибо :)